# How to Update the View from the Model

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm

So I am trying to implement the MVVM pattern in a simple sample app. Essentially my app allows a user to choose from a list of search providers in a SettingsPage, and then in the MainPage when the user clicks the 'search' button he or she will be navigated to the search provider's website. Everything seems to work ok, no errors, except when navigating directly back to MainPage from SettingsPage the search property does not seem to be updated. Everything is fine though when the application is completely exited and launched fresh. What I have is as follows

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheBrowser.Navigate(App.ViewModel.SearchProvider.Address);
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

MainViewMode.cs

```
public ListItem SearchProvider { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
    {
        SearchProvider = Settings.SearchProvider.Value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and in my SettingsPage is where I am allowin ga user to select a search provider

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
private void PopulateSearchProviderList()
    {
        searchProviderList = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();

        searchProviderList.Add(new ListItem { Name = "Bing", Address = "http://www.bing.com" });
        searchProviderList.Add(new ListItem { Name = "Google", Address = "http://www.google.com" });

        SearchProviderListPicker.ItemsSource = searchProviderList;
    }

private void stk_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchProviderListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var selectedItem = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as TestApp.Classes.ListItem;

            Settings.SearchProvider.Value = selectedItem; //Setting the search provider
        }
    }
```

and finally my ListItem class which is fairly straightforward

ListItem.cs

```
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

So essentially I am not updating the ViewModel correctly based on the SettingsPage, but I am unsure of how to go about this properly.

Comment: Are you using any MVVM frameworks such as MVVM Light? Can you also post your xaml where you bind your SearchProvider?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged("propertyName")` for the item to update in the UI.

For example (assuming the `Name` and `Address` properties are bound to your UI elements.)

```
private string name;
private string address;

 public string Name
 {
     get { return name;}
     set { 
            name = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
         }

 }

 public string Address
 {
     get { return address; }
     set { 
             address = value ;
             OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
          }
 }
```

Comment: I changed my ListItem class to reflect those changes, and put a propertyChanged handler in there, but nothing changed?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and verified that your PopulateSearchProviderList method actually runs? How do you pass this information to the MainViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues I can see. We'll start from there.

- Your MainViewModel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Your `SearchProvider` setter needs to raise `PropertyChanged`
- You need to set the value of the `SearchProvider`. Currently that is only performed in the constructor which is probably why you are seeing things working on app startup only.
- You need to make sure you are correctly binding the value of `SearchProvider` in your xaml. If you post your xaml we can check that out too.

In your ViewModel, add:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

Update the SearchProvider property to something like:

```
private ListItem searchProvider;
public ListItem SearchProvider
{
    get { return searchProvider; }
    set
    {
        searchProvider = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```